# React Router with Params giving 404 error

Tags: reactjs, laravel

Below are the routes in my project

```
   <Route exact path="/admin-users" component={User}/>
   <Route exact path="/admin-events" component={Events}/>
   <Route exact path="/admin-createEvent" component={CreateEvent}/>
   <Route exact path="/admin/:id" component={Home}/>
   <Route exact path="/xx/:id" component={Home}/>
```

Iam able to go on regular routes like '/admin-users' but not when they have params in it like '/xx/1'.
It gives 404 error.

I have  in my index.php
I have tried replacing my node_modules with another project that is working just fine.
I have tried downgrading my react version.

Still the error persists.

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: /xx/1 seems to work for me in this example. However it's not a parameter, it's a part of the path. https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-wiles-kfkw2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: typo error . plese read that as /xx/:id. Infact all routes with params are giving 404 error

Comment: It works for me even with :id in the codesandbox. I think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Solved finally.
the problem was in routes in laravel project. All I had to do was
Route::get( '/{path?}', function(){ return view('layouts.app' ); })->where('path', '.*');
Thanks